# Roblox script error: ServerScriptService.CheckpointsScript:31: attempt to index nil with 'leaderstats'

Tags: lua, roblox

I can not resolve this by my self.

Thank You for helping.

This is my first stackoverflow question :3

Roblox Studio information:
Latest available version as of 2022 October 03
Picture of about window:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo6Br.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7Jot.png

The output:
ServerScriptService.CheckpointsScript:31: attempt to index nil with 'leaderstats'

The code:

```lua
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local CheckpointsFolder = game.Workspace.Checkpoints

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player
    
    local Stage = Instance.new("IntValue")
    Stage.Name = "Stage"
    Stage.Parent = leaderstats
    
    --player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
        
    --  local checkpoint = CheckpointsFolder:FindFirstChild(Stage.Value)
        
    --  player.Character..CFrame = CFrame.new(checkpoint.PrimaryPart.CFrame.Position.Y + 5 =, checkpoint.PrimaryPart.CFrame.Rotation)
        
    --end)
    
end)

for _, v in pairs(CheckpointsFolder:GetChildren()) do
    
    if v:IsA("BasePart") then
        v.Touched:Connect(function(part)
            
            local player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(part.Parent)
            local stageValue = player.leaderstats.Stage
            
            if player and stageValue.Value < tonumber(v.Name) then
                
                stageValue.Value = v.Name
                
            end
        end)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is coming from this line

```lua
local stageValue = player.leaderstats.Stage
```

And that is because the Touched event fires for any object that touches it. And you need to make sure that `player` actually exists.

You are doing this already, you just need to move this line inside your safety check.

```lua
            local player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(part.Parent)
            if player then
                local stage = player.leaderstats.Stage
                local currentStage = tonumber(v.Name)
                if stage.Value < currentStage then
                    stage.Value = currentStage 
                end
            end
```